# Getting a navigation.navigate type error after spliting the mainscreen into components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I was working on my app with two screens a Main Screen and a Details Screen everything was working, but the code was long, so I tried to split everything into reusable components which caused a 
navigation.navigates type error for some reason.

I checked the code multiple times everything makes perfect sense to me is there something am missing here, how do I fixed this error?

Am using react navigation version 5 for the first time.

Here is a sample of the code used:

MainScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, FlatList } from "react-native";
import ArticleList from "../components/ArticleList";

function MainScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>


      {/* show the data in a flatlist */}
      <ArticleList />

    </View>
  );
}
MainScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    headerShown: false,
  };
};

export default MainScreen;
```

DetailScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { SharedElement } from "react-native-shared-element";
import { TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
const DetailScreen = (props) => {
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  const { data } = props.route.params;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <SharedElement id={`item.${data.id}.photo`}>
          <Image
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={{ uri: data.image }}
            style={{
              width: 400,
              height: 300,
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
              borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
            }}
          />
        </SharedElement>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            alignItems: "center",
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 14,
            left: 10,
          }}
        >
          <SharedElement id={`item.${data.id}.profilePic`}>
            <Image
              resizeMode="cover"
              source={{ uri: data.profilePic }}
              style={{
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                borderRadius: 10,
                marginRight: 14,
              }}
            />
          </SharedElement>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <SharedElement id={`item.${data.id}.username`}>
                <Text
                  style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "bold" }}
                >
                  {data.username}
                </Text>
              </SharedElement>
              <SharedElement id={`item.${data.id}.readtime`}>
                <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 14 }}>
                  {data.readtime}
                </Text>
              </SharedElement>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Feather name="bookmark" size={30} color="white" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      <ScrollView style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingTop: 14 }}>
        <SharedElement
          id={`item.${data.id}.text`}
          style={{ width: width - 30, marginBottom: 14 }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, fontWeight: "bold", lineHeight: 32 }}>
            {data.title}
          </Text>
        </SharedElement>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 14,
            lineHeight: 28,
            textAlign: "justify",
            opacity: 0.5,
          }}
        >
          Paragraph 1
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 14,
            lineHeight: 28,
            textAlign: "justify",
            opacity: 0.5,
          }}
        >
          Paragraph 2
        </Text>
        <View
          style={{
            marginVertical: 25,
            paddingBottom: 20,
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 12, alignItems: "center" }}
          >
            <Feather name="heart" size={16} color="orange" />
            <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}>3.4k Likes</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={{ position: "absolute", top: 40, left: 10 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>
          <Feather name="arrow-left" size={24} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
export default DetailScreen;
```

ArticleList.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { SharedElement } from "react-native-shared-element";
import TouchableScale from "react-native-touchable-scale";
import { data } from "../data";

function ArticleList({ navigation }) {
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{ paddingHorizontal: 30 }}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <View>
                <TouchableScale
                  activeScale={0.9}
                  tension={50}
                  friction={7}
                  useNativeDriver
                  onPress={() =>
                    navigation.navigate("DetailScreen", { data: item })
                  }
                >
                  {/* to show the horizental news list*/}
                  <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.photo`}>
                    <Image
                      source={{ uri: item.image }}
                      style={{
                        width: width - 100,
                        height: height - 350,
                        borderRadius: 14,
                        marginRight: 30,
                      }}
                    />
                  </SharedElement>
                  {/* to show the news titles inside the pictures*/}
                  <SharedElement
                    id={`item.${item.id}.text`}
                    style={{
                      width: width - 100,
                      position: "absolute",
                      bottom: 90,
                      left: 10,
                      paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.blogTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                  </SharedElement>
                  {/* to show the pictre of the author of the news article*/}
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: "row",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      position: "absolute",
                      bottom: 20,
                      left: 20,
                    }}
                  >
                    <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.profilePic`}>
                      <Image
                        resizeMode="cover"
                        source={{ uri: item.profilePic }}
                        style={styles.blogProfilePic}
                      />
                    </SharedElement>
                  </View>
                  {/* to show the name of the author and read time of article*/}
                  <View>
                    <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.username`}>
                      <Text style={styles.blogUsername}>{item.username}</Text>
                    </SharedElement>
                    <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.readtime`}>
                      <Text style={styles.readtime}>{item.readtime}</Text>
                    </SharedElement>
                  </View>
                </TouchableScale>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  blogTitle: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    lineHeight: 28,
  },
  blogProfilePic: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginRight: 14,
  },
  blogUsername: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  readtime: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "white",
  },
});

export default ArticleList;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { createSharedElementStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-shared-element";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MainScreen from "./app/screens/MainScreen";
import DetailScreen from "./app/screens/DetailScreen";

const Stack = createSharedElementStackNavigator();

const App = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MainScreen"
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="DetailScreen"
          component={DetailScreen}
          options={(navigation) => ({
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current: { progress } }) => {
              return {
                cardStyle: {
                  opacity: progress,
                },
              };
            },
          })}
          sharedElements={(route) => {
            const { data } = route.params;
            return [
              {
                id: `item.${data.id}.photo`,
                animation: "move",
                resize: "clip",
                align: "center-top",
              },
              {
                id: `item.${data.id}.text`,
                animation: "fade",
                resize: "clip",
                align: "left-center",
              },
              {
                id: `item.${data.id}.profilePic`,
                animation: "move",
                resize: "clip",
                align: "left-center",
              },
              {
                id: `item.${data.id}.username`,
                animation: "fade",
                resize: "clip",
                align: "left-center",
              },
              {
                id: `item.${data.id}.readtime`,
                animation: "fade",
                resize: "clip",
                align: "left-center",
              },
            ];
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default App;
```

My apologies for the long samples of code I tried to keep everything that is connected directly to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the you are accessing navigation outside the navigation stack. When you moved the flatlist to to ArticleList its outside the navigation and it wont get the navigation prop.
You can handle this in two ways.

1. You can simply pass the navigation from the main screen

   function MainScreen({ navigation }) {
     return (
       
         {/* show the data in a flatlist */}
         < ArticleList navigation={navigation} />
       
     );
   }
2. You can use the [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) hook to access navigation outside navigation.